# SSIS - Conditional Split when rows are not null

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, conditional-compilation

I have `.xlsx` sheet where data starts from `A1:AB199`. I am trying to extract data from Row `A6:AB48` and ignore the rest.

Started creating a `Conditional Split` so SSIS package can start from Row `A6` and end at Row `AB48` but failing. Please guide

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your Dataflow and the error message you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [In your Data Flow task, you will need to set the "OpenRowset" Custom Property of your Excel Connection](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/947fa27e-e31f-4108-a889-18acebce9217/ssis-excel-import-skip-first-rows?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Or

[Another MSDN Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/20944506-5276-41e7-8b65-7f36d6e4bdaa/can-i-create-a-ssis-package-to-get-only-row-12-to-row-123-from-an-excel-sheet?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

1 - Excel Source -> Variables -> In Data Access Mode select "Table name or view name variable"
2- In the variable name select a variable that you had made before "MyVar"
3- Go To variable select "MyVar" and type "TabName$A12:H125"

Answer (score 0):

- Before *conditional split* add a *script component* with one output column of type `DT_BOOL` . In my example i assume that is named `OutColumn`.
- In the script window add the following Code:

  ```
  Private m_intRowCounter as integer = 0


  Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)  

  m_intRowCounter += 1

  if  m_intRowCounter  >= 6

  Row.OutCOlumn = True

  Else

  Row.OutCOlumn = False

  End If

  End Sub
  ```
- In the *conditional split* split row on `OutColumn` : if true take rows to destination

Hope it helps